# What is the best way to learn Expressions Blend 2?

Tags: expression-blend, expression-blend-2

What is the best way to quickly get up to speed on Microsoft Expressions Blend 2?

Are there some good web sites that can get me started or does someone have a good book that they would recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression Blend is used in creating Sliverlight XAML.  I would start with [sliverlight.net](http://silverlight.net)

This is where you should get started.

http://silverlight.net/GetStarted/

Here is Scott G [blog on Blend and Sliverlight.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/02/28/first-look-at-using-expression-blend-with-silverlight-2.aspx)

Comment: Cool, I have not seen these sites before.

Answer (score 0):

There is a decent book: **Foundation Expression Blend 2** by Victor Gaudioso.

It covers the basics of what the various widgets in Blend do.  FWIW, it worked for me.