# Expression Blend Books?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

Are there any good Expression Blend books out there yet? The help file is better than I'd expected it to be. But I'd really like to get ramped up faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you ["Microsoft Expression Blend Bible"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470055030) by Gurdy and Mary Leete. This book is definitely worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a book from the Designer's perspective, the best book out there currently is Foundation Expression Blend 2, by Victor Guadioso. It reminds me of the older PeachPit Press books for graphics programs. There is some code in the book, as well, but it is more tool focused.

Answer (score 1):

Some related discussions on SO that might be of help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562948/do-you-have-any-recommendations-on-blend-xaml-books-tutorials-for-designers

[What is the best way to learn Expressions Blend 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369551/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-expressions-blend-2)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625407/expression-blend-2-wpf-book